# Lagom service reply on topic

Tags: scala, lagom

I'm implementing a set of Lagom services and I have one that's planned to purely read from a topic and replying back to that topic.

I can't seem to find any docs on how to do this? All of the subscriber examples map from a message to Done and all of the publish examples are mapping from the event store events to publish external messages.

Comment: As far as I know only one service can publish to a Kafka topic. That service doesn't publish messages by calling a publish method, you can only let the framework publish a `Source`.